# Rest API to update

Tags: php, mysql, rest, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter REST API. I want to update table with Update API but getting error.

**Here is my API code:**

```
public function data_put(){

    $data = $this->input->input_stream();
    $this->User_model->updateuser($data);
    $message = [
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'], 
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'email'=> $data['email'],
        'phone'=> $data['phone'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
        'city' => $data['city'],
        'state' => $data['state'],
        'country' => $data['country'],
        'postalcode' => $data['postalcode']         

    ];
    $this->set_response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); 
 }
```

**Model:**

```
public function updateuser($data){  

    $imp = "'" . implode("','", $data) . "'";
    $this->db->query("CALL spupdateuser($imp)"); 

}
```

**Error**
Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE table.spupdateuser; expected 10, got 1

Comment: This error means, you need to send 10 values to the procedure. But you are passing only one value `$imp`.

Comment: Yes but i'm passing all 10 values, if i print $imp i can see 10 values

Comment: Can you post your db object as well ?

Comment: try to print your '$imp' before querying it. Check if it is in array format or some other string format like json.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your $data is in JSON format and not exactly and array.

Why don't you try -

```
$datastrip = "'" . $data['firstname'] .','. $data['lastname'] .','.
 $data['email'] .','. $data['phone'] .','.
$data['address'] .','. $data['city'] .','.
$data['state'] .','. $data['country'] .','.
 $data['postalcode']  . "'"
```

and then

```
$this->User_model->updateuser($datastrip);
```